# AWS CloudFront limitation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to use AWS cloud Front service for one of my request. I am able to complete this functionality, but when i search for the limitation of AWS Cloud front i have found it will support 200 web distributions per account. Now my question is i am going to use only one web distribution url, with sub urls, Example: http:AWScloudfronturl/object/folder1/1.jpg
         http:AWScloudfronturl/object/folder2/2.png
here http:AWScloudfronturl is my base web distribution. in this case how many urls i can work? is there any limitation for this?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the limitation 200 distribution is for the distributions you are going to create using AWS CF. The sub urls from same web distribution are not counted as a separate web distribution.

Check this screenshot below. So in the screenshot there are 10 Web distribution separate for each application. So again sub urls are not separate web distribution they are part of same web distribution.

[image]